# Is dual-channel memory or PCIe NVMe SSD more important for overall performance?

Tags: memory, ssd, pcie

I am currently looking for a new 14" notebook and I'm choosing between the Dell E7470 and the Lenovo T460s. (Unfortunately I cannot post links to these due to <10 reputation.)

Other differences aside, I can see that

- the Dell E7470 has two memory banks and therefore supports a dual-channel configuration, but although it can accommodate a PCIe NVMe SSD too, it will [run at half of the PCIe bandwidth](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/anyone-upgrade-a-pm951-in-a-laptop.791497/page-2#post-10264901).
- the Lenovo T460s comes with choices of PCIe NVMe SSDs, but has 4 GB of RAM soldered, so if I add more than another 4 GB of RAM, then it will not run in a dual-channel configuration.

Which one would be more important for overall performance, dual-channel memory or an NVMe SSD at the full PCIe bandwith?

My performance requirements are not that high, just some Java and PHP software development and running virtual machines, but I would like to have something that will still be sufficient in a few years. (My current notebook is nearly 10 years old!)

Comment: Not an answer, but If half the pcie bandwidth is still better than SATA3, then I'd go with the flexibility of adding more ram dimms (even higher capacity dimms), especially if I am running VMs of some sort. Is M2 the only storage option on 7470? Do you have the option of adding a secondary storage drive?