# How much practical benefit from SATA III to PCIe SSD upgrade if PCIe at half bandwidth?

Tags: ssd, pcie

In [another question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/is-dual-channel-memory-or-pcie-nvme-ssd-more-important-for-overall-performance), I asked how one specific difference between the Dell E7470 and the Lenovo T460s affects performance.

Based on other differences between these two notebooks, I'm leaning towards the Dell E7470.

Although the Dell E7470 supports PCIe NVMe SSDs, they will [run at half of the PCIe bandwidth](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/anyone-upgrade-a-pm951-in-a-laptop.791497/page-2#post-10264901). If I buy this notebook, how much would I still benefit from replacing the stock SATA III SSD with a PCIe NVMe SSD?

I'm talking about performance gain noticable in practice, with my main usage being software development and running virtual machines.

Comment: I see you've managed to end up with two accounts. If you use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page and select 'I need to merge user profiles', the staff team can merge the two accounts together so that all your posts appear under one account.